# How long does it take to mint a new tag badge?

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

I just got a tag badge on [linguistics.se] as the first user for that specific tag. It took surprisingly long from fulfilling the criteria to receiving the badge. So my question out of curiosity: How long does it take to mint a brand new tag badge?